Python decorator class, with and without args, decorating class methods, and passes type checking
I want a Python decorator that:

Is a class
Can be used with or without args
Passes type checking with mypy
Can decorate class functions

I've found answers here that answer most combinations of these, but not all four.
This is the closest I've come.  Python 3.8.
#!/usr/bin/env python3.8
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import (
    Callable,
    TypeVar,
    Generic,
    Optional,
    Any,
    Type,
    cast,
    overload,
)
from typing_extensions import Concatenate, ParamSpec, reveal_type

T_o = TypeVar("T_o")  # Type of the class instance
T_ret = TypeVar("T_ret")  # Return type of the decorated function
P = ParamSpec("P")  # Param spec for decorated unbound function arguments


class MyDecoCls(Generic[T_o, T_ret, P]):

    @overload  # Decorator with args:  __init__(self, arg1=..., arg2=...)
    def __init__(self, /, arg1: bool = False, arg2: bool = False) -> None: ...

    @overload  # Decorator without args:  __init__(self, funct)
    def __init__(
        self, funct: Callable[Concatenate[T_o, P], T_ret], /
    ) -> None: ...

    def __init__(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        self.with_args = not (args and callable(args[0]))
        print(f"In __init__({self}, {args}, {kwargs})")
        self.funct: Optional[Callable[Concatenate[T_o, P], T_ret]] = None
        self.arg1 = kwargs.get("arg1", False)
        self.arg2 = kwargs.get("arg2", False)
        if not self.with_args:
            self.funct = cast(Callable[Concatenate[T_o, P], T_ret], args[0])

    def __get__(self, instance: T_o, owner: Type[T_o], /) -> Callable[P, T_ret]:
        # Decorator without args:  __get__(self, obj, type(obj)) -> wrapper
        print(f"In __get__({self}, {instance}, {owner})")
        assert instance
        assert self.funct

        def wrapper(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T_ret:
            assert self.funct
            ret = self.funct(instance, *args, **kwargs)  # Use instance here
            print(f"In wrapper({args}, {kwargs}) -> {ret} (__get__)")
            print(f"    self.funct: {self.funct}; instance: {instance}")
            return ret

        reveal_type(wrapper)

        # Explicitly cast the wrapper to the correct type
        return cast(Callable[P, T_ret], wrapper)

    reveal_type(__get__)

    def __call__(
        self, funct: Callable[Concatenate[T_o, P], T_ret], /
    ) -> Callable[Concatenate[T_o, P], T_ret]:
        # Decorator with args:  __call__(self, funct) -> wrapper
        print(f"In __call__({self}, {funct})")
        assert self.with_args
        assert callable(funct)
        self.funct = funct

        def wrapper(self: T_o, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T_ret:
            ret = funct(self, *args, **kwargs)
            print(f"In wrapper({self}, {args}, {kwargs}) -> {ret}  (__call__)")
            return ret

        reveal_type(wrapper)

        return cast(Callable[Concatenate[T_o, P], T_ret], wrapper)

    reveal_type(__call__)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        args = "with args" if self.with_args else "without args"
        return f"<MyDecoCls object ({args}) {hex(id(self))[-6:]}>"


# Example usage
class Foo:
    @MyDecoCls
    def bar(self, i: int) -> int:
        print(f"{self}.bar({i})")
        return i * 2

    reveal_type(bar)

    @MyDecoCls(arg1=True)
    def baz(self, /, i: int) -> int:
        print(f"{self}.baz(i={i})")
        return i * 4

    reveal_type(baz)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "<Foo object>"


# Test the implementation using the example usage
f = Foo()
res: int
print(f"object f = {f}")
print(f"running bar: {(res := f.bar(42))}")
assert res == 42 * 2, f"res was {res}"
print(f"running baz: {(res := f.baz(i=13))}")
assert res == 13 * 4, f"res was {res} != 13 * 4"

The script runs correctly.
Runtime type is 'function'
Runtime type is 'function'
In __init__(<MyDecoCls object (without args) 4da340>, (<function Foo.bar at 0x7f0dab2abf70>,), {})
Runtime type is 'MyDecoCls'
In __init__(<MyDecoCls object (with args) 43d160>, (), {'arg1': True})
In __call__(<MyDecoCls object (with args) 43d160>, <function Foo.baz at 0x7f0dab2a5040>)
Runtime type is 'function'
Runtime type is 'function'
object f = <Foo object>
In __get__(<MyDecoCls object (without args) 4da340>, <Foo object>, <class '__main__.Foo'>)
Runtime type is 'function'
<Foo object>.bar(42)
In wrapper((42,), {}) -> 84 (__get__)
    self.funct: <function Foo.bar at 0x7f0dab2abf70>; instance: <Foo object>
running bar: 84
<Foo object>.baz(i=13)
In wrapper(<Foo object>, (), {'i': 13}) -> 52  (__call__)
running baz: 52

But mypy --strict fails.
foo.py:52: note: Revealed type is "def (*P.args, **P.kwargs) -> T_ret`2"
foo.py:57: note: Revealed type is "def (foo.MyDecoCls[T_o`1, T_ret`2, P`3], T_o`1, Type[T_o`1]) -> def (*P.args, **P.kwargs) -> T_ret`2"
foo.py:73: note: Revealed type is "def (self: T_o`1, *P.args, **P.kwargs) -> T_ret`2"
foo.py:77: note: Revealed type is "def (foo.MyDecoCls[T_o`1, T_ret`2, P`3], def (T_o`1, *P.args, **P.kwargs) -> T_ret`2) -> def (T_o`1, *P.args, **P.kwargs) -> T_ret`2"
foo.py:91: note: Revealed type is "foo.MyDecoCls[foo.Foo, builtins.int, [i: builtins.int]]"
foo.py:93: error: Argument 1 to "__call__" of "MyDecoCls" has incompatible type "Callable[[Foo, int], int]"; expected "Callable[[Never, VarArg(Never), KwArg(Never)], Never]"  [arg-type]
foo.py:98: note: Revealed type is "def (Never, *Never, **Never) -> Never"
foo.py:110: error: Invalid self argument "Foo" to attribute function "baz" with type "Callable[[Never, VarArg(Never), KwArg(Never)], Never]"  [misc]
foo.py:110: error: Argument "i" to "baz" of "Foo" has incompatible type "int"; expected "Never"  [arg-type]
Found 3 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)

The problem is in the decorator with args.  How can this be made to work?

Why does it need to be a class?

Second @chepner: you try to make it a generic class, but generics must be resolvable during instantiation. MyDecoCls(arg1=True) does not allow to solve for P and typevars. The closest is this (note that your casts of wrapper aren't necessary if you make self posonly), but it breaks typing for self.funct. If you don't need that attribute or are OK with it being potentially incompatible (the only way to get that would be to parametrize with-args form explicitly), that should work fine.

@chepner:  here is an article (random link googled with "python decorator class") explaining class decorators, and includes use cases.  This generic example is meant to be adaptable to any particular use case.

@STerliakov:  Wow, I spent way more hours trying to figure this out on my own than it took you to find and answer this question here!  In retrospect, it seems obvious, that __call__() is independent of the rest of the apparatus, and just needs its own generics.  (And me setting self.funct was just another clue that I was looking at this in the wrong way.)  Your changes fix mypy --strict, and the type: ignored line should just be removed.  Submit that as an answer & I'll mark it accepted.  Thank you!

This is a surprisingly great question not about something impossible in python's static typing.
Basically, whenever you declare a Generic class, there are only two ways to solve generic variables involved. The first is a common one: you define a constructor (__new__ or __init__, yes, those aren't really "constructors", but let's leave this discussion to language-lawyers) depending on these variables, and the type checker solves for them. The second is less common, though still encountered in wild: you can provide these params explicitly (imagine x: defaultdict[str, int] = defaultdict(int) - there's no way to infer key types without annotation), either by typed assignment or by parametrizing the class (x = defaultdict[str, int](int)). Either way, you need to know all generic variables when the class is instantiated (or, at worst, instantiated and immediately assigned to a typed variable). There's no way to say "please infer it from a later call" - that's because often definition of "next call" is ambiguous, especially if several methods depend on this variable.
Now the second one is almost unusable in this case: you'd have to annotate with essentially duplicates of method signatures. So the first way is preferred (as usual).
It works well when funct is passed directly to the constructor - there is enough information to solve all of P, T_o and T_ret. However, the first (with-args) overload does not involve any of these variables. In such cases type checker can only infer something like pyright's "Unknown" and (often) issue a warning like "need type annotation for ...". However, there's no way to put an annotation there, hence mypy just silently falls back to Never inference, without an early diagnostic. When you do MyDecoCls(arg1=True), it has type MyDecoCls[Never, Never, Never] - not something you can __call__ with any function.
Now we know what the problem is, but how to fix that? Your __call__ method only applies to with-args scenario, so it doesn't care about class' variables - they will always1 be resolved to Never in such case. Let's forget about those class-bound vars and introduce new triple of them, bound only to __call__ method.
Let's also get rid of those ridiculous casts for wrapper functions: first one is completely unnecessary even in your snippet, and another one just needs making self posonly.
# These three parametrize no-args version
T_o = TypeVar("T_o")  # Type of the class instance
T_ret = TypeVar("T_ret")  # Return type of the decorated function
P = ParamSpec("P")  # Param spec for decorated unbound function arguments

# These three only apply to with-args case
T_o2 = TypeVar("T_o2")
T_ret2 = TypeVar("T_ret2")
P2 = ParamSpec("P2")


class MyDecoCls(Generic[T_o, T_ret, P]):
    @overload  # Decorator with args:  __init__(self, arg1=..., arg2=...)
    def __init__(self, /, arg1: bool = False, arg2: bool = False) -> None: ...

    @overload  # Decorator without args:  __init__(self, funct)
    def __init__(
        self, funct: Callable[Concatenate[T_o, P], T_ret], /
    ) -> None: ...

    def __init__(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        self.with_args = not (args and callable(args[0]))
        print(f"In __init__({self}, {args}, {kwargs})")
        self.funct: Optional[Callable[Concatenate[T_o, P], T_ret]] = None
        self.arg1 = kwargs.get("arg1", False)
        self.arg2 = kwargs.get("arg2", False)
        if not self.with_args:
            self.funct = cast(Callable[Concatenate[T_o, P], T_ret], args[0])

    def __get__(self, instance: T_o, owner: Type[T_o], /) -> Callable[P, T_ret]:
        # Decorator without args:  __get__(self, obj, type(obj)) -> wrapper
        print(f"In __get__({self}, {instance}, {owner})")
        assert instance
        assert self.funct

        def wrapper(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T_ret:
            assert self.funct
            ret = self.funct(instance, *args, **kwargs)  # Use instance here
            print(f"In wrapper({args}, {kwargs}) -> {ret} (__get__)")
            print(f"    self.funct: {self.funct}; instance: {instance}")
            return ret

        reveal_type(wrapper)
        return wrapper

    reveal_type(__get__)

    def __call__(
        self, funct: Callable[Concatenate[T_o2, P2], T_ret2], /
    ) -> Callable[Concatenate[T_o2, P2], T_ret2]:
        # Decorator with args:  __call__(self, funct) -> wrapper
        print(f"In __call__({self}, {funct})")
        assert self.with_args
        assert callable(funct)
        # See note [1] regarding safety of this
        self.funct = funct  # type: ignore[assignment]

        def wrapper(self: T_o2, /, *args: P2.args, **kwargs: P2.kwargs) -> T_ret2:
            ret = funct(self, *args, **kwargs)
            print(f"In wrapper({self}, {args}, {kwargs}) -> {ret}  (__call__)")
            return ret

        reveal_type(wrapper)
        return wrapper

    reveal_type(__call__)

This now validates well against your example (playground).
However, this is a case where using a function decorator instead can be much more intuitive. Even if your class is much larger in fact, it still can be refactored to a group of functions. If you go this way, no scoping issues like that will arise. Here's how I would tackle this myself (playground, passes mypy --strict):
T_o = TypeVar("T_o")  # Type of the class instance
T_ret = TypeVar("T_ret")  # Return type of the decorated function
P = ParamSpec("P")  # Param spec for decorated unbound function arguments

Fn: TypeAlias = Callable[Concatenate[T_o, P], T_ret]


@overload
def my_deco(fn: Fn[T_o, P, T_ret], /) -> Fn[T_o, P, T_ret]: ...
@overload
def my_deco(
    *, arg1: bool = False, arg2: bool = False
) -> Callable[[Fn[T_o, P, T_ret]], Fn[T_o, P, T_ret]]: ...
def my_deco(
    fn: Fn[T_o, P, T_ret] | None = None, 
    /, 
    *, 
    arg1: bool = False, 
    arg2: bool = False
) -> Fn[T_o, P, T_ret] | Callable[[Fn[T_o, P, T_ret]], Fn[T_o, P, T_ret]]:
    if fn is not None:
        
        def wrapper(instance: T_o, /, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T_ret:
            ret = fn(instance, *args, **kwargs)  # Use instance here
            print(f"In wrapper({args}, {kwargs}) -> {ret} (__get__)")
            print(f"    self.funct: {fn}; instance: {instance}")
            return ret

        reveal_type(wrapper)
        return wrapper
    else:
        
        def outer(funct: Fn[T_o, P, T_ret]) -> Fn[T_o, P, T_ret]:
            
            def wrapper(self: T_o, /, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T_ret:
                ret = funct(self, *args, **kwargs)
                print(f"In wrapper({self}, {args}, {kwargs}) -> {ret}  (__call__)")
                return ret
    
            reveal_type(wrapper)
            return wrapper
        
        return outer


[1] Well, not always. You can parametrize the decorator directly, potentially creating a type-unsafe scenario.
class A:
     @MyDecoCls[A, None, []](arg1=True)
     def fn(self, x: int) -> None: ...

This will work in some sense of this word (fn will still have correct type (self, x: int) -> None), but in fact you violate the contract (MyDecoCls was created to handle only def _(self) -> None functions, but you feed another thing to it). That shouldn't be a problem in real code, though.

...and this question was very aesthetically pleasant, my editor highlights this soo beautifully (to be fair, this is usually indication of high-level metaprogramming or overengineering - or both!):

