Type hints lost when a decorator is wrapped as a classmethod?
Consider the following code:
from typing import Any, Callable, Coroutine

class Cache[**P, R]:
    @classmethod
    def decorate(cls, **params):
        def decorator(f: Callable[P, Coroutine[Any, Any, R]]) -> Callable[P, Coroutine[Any, Any, R]]:
            return f # in the real world, we instantiate a Cache here
        return decorator

@Cache.decorate()
async def some_function(i: int) -> int:
    return i + 1

cached_function = Cache.decorate()(some_function)


If I ask pyright the type of Cache.decorate before the @classmethod wrapper (inspecting the word decorate in the above code), it returns:
(method) def decorate(
    cls: type[Self@Cache[P@Cache, R@Cache]],
    **params: Unknown
) -> ((f: ((**P@Cache) -> (Coroutine[Any, Any, R@Cache])) -> ((**P@Cache) -> Coroutine[Any, Any, R@Cache]))

That looks to me like it understands that P (the argument types) and R (the return types) are plumbed through correctly.
However, if I ask it to introspect Cache.decorate in the context where it's being used as a decorator, it returns:
(method) def decorate(**params: Unknown) -> ((f: ((...) -> Coroutine[Any, Any, Unknown])) -> ((...) -> Coroutine[Any, Any, Unknown]))

...which is to say, the relationship between input types and output types has been entirely discarded!

Did you mean to parametrize decorator rather than decorate (i.e., decorator[**P, R](f: Callable[...]))? Parametrizing decorate should also lead to the same result (indirect link, original link too long).

By the way, please don't use typing.Callable, typing.Coroutine or any such legacy aliases. You are on 3.12, not 3.8; use collections.abc.Callable and collections.abc.Coroutine instead.

Ough, please show more real code here. Are there any other Cache methods? What's decorator really doing instead of return f? As currently written, your Cache class shouldn't be generic at all. Similar (but not enough to be a dupe) recent Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78921314/python-decorator-class-with-and-without-args-decorating-class-methods-and-pas/78925369#78925369

@STerliakov, ...the real code would be going far beyond a MRE for the immediate problem. Moreover, building a clean-room implementation I can publish under CC BY-SA would be a time commitment and risk introducing its own bugs. Assume that a Cache object actually stores a bunch of asyncio tasks wrapping coroutines that invoke an individual function, keyed by arguments to that function, expiration details, &c.

Okay, then the primary question: why is Cache generic at all? Do you ever use instances of it, especially outside of the class itself? If not, it still shouldn't be generic. Generic typevars only apply to instances, they are meaningless at the class level.

@STerliakov, what we return from the decorator in the "real" version is not actually the real function, but a Cache object that masquerades as the original function, implementing __call__ with its original signature. Occasionally, cache-aware code that wants to do introspection will cast that function to the Cache object to be able to inspect or modify state, in which using the typevars in the cast means that we know what we're getting when we inspect or what types we can pass to methods.

Oh, cool, this is getting somewhere! You don't need to return a Callable then, return a Cache instead: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.12&flags=strict&gist=3c1d0f749ffa932823da1b7ecff7d738. Does that playground represent your usecase well enough? It's similar to existing answer, but I think that Cache itself being callable is quite important here. Your decorate is then an "alternative constructor", which is supported by typing systen way better than arbitrary generics transformations and dependencies.

@STerliakov, ...yes, I do in fact think that's on-point.

decorator depends on two contextual type variables: P and R. In the context of the Cache class, these are not known, but assumed to be known by Pyright at call time.
However, when Cache.decorate() is called, Pyright does not get enough information to resolve P and R (no explicit type arguments and no arguments), so these two are resolved as Unknown.
A simple fix is to parametrize Cache explicitly:
(playground)
@Cache[[int], int].decorate()
async def some_function(i: int) -> int:
    return i + 1

reveal_type(some_function)  # (int) -> Coroutine[Any, Any, int]

However, this does not get you to the root of the problem, which is that you are not correctly specifying what you want.
Cache is generic over P and R, so there must exist a way in which Pyright can infer the types correspond to those parameters. Normally, these are handled by passing arguments to the function creating that class, commonly __new__/__init__ and factory @classmethods.
# Hypothetical usages
Cache(return_value, *args, **kwargs)
Cache.factory(return_value, *args, **kwargs)

# This is also possible, as shown, but rarer
Cache[[int], int]()

decorate() is a factory method, but it does not create instances of Cache on its own. It takes some arguments, but these do not affect the type of the decorated some_function() nor the type of the to-be-created Cache.
Instead, decorate() is meant to create decorators that themselves create instances of Cache. It is these decorators that you want to parametrize, because they are the ones receiving the decorated functions and responsible for creating Caches.
(playground)
class Cache[**P, R]:

    @classmethod
    def decorate(cls, **params: Any):
        def decorator[**P2, R2](f: Callable[P2, Coroutine[Any, Any, R2]]) -> ...:
            #        ^^^^^^^^^^
            return f
        
        return decorator

reveal_type(Cache.decorate())
# (f: (**P2@decorator) -> Coroutine[Any, Any, R2@decorator]) -> ((**P2@decorator) -> Coroutine[Any, Any, R2@decorator])

reveal_type(some_function)
# (i: int) -> Coroutine[Any, Any, int]


I'm not sure that I'm convinced P2 and R2 should be distinct from P and R -- in the real-world case, when we decorate a function, the Cache instance we create is distinct to that function's argument and return signatures (storing values with types based on that signature). That said, this did provide the pointer I need to fix the immediate practical problem.

@CharlesDuffy They need to be named differently due to type-checking-time scoping rules. Pyright wouldn't like it if you name them the same. They are otherwise the same, yes.

(I'll be using the "old-style" generics in this answer as they have broader tooling support and look way more natural for me, but this should be trivial to rewrite using new-style PEP695 type parameters)
P and T in your example have class scope: they are resolved for every instance of the class. Your decorate is entirely untyped, so there isn't much to expect: a conformant checker must interpret that as def decorate(cls, **kwargs: Any) -> Any, but pyright decided not to be conformant in this regard for some reason.
When returning a Callable, there's no relation with an actual Cache instance, so there's no point where P and T can be resolved, ever.
You hinted in comments that Cache is in fact callable, so you don't have to return a Callable and can use Cache as a return type directly. Then decorate becomes essentially an "alternative constructor" for Cache and that makes typevar resolution possible. We can use another pair of type vars
not used in the class itself to denote "given a callable, returns a corresponding Cache instance".
These type variables should be different, because this classmethod really works similar to a constructor, and even when called on instance produces a new Cache object with new variables not restricted to existing ones.
from __future__ import annotations

from collections.abc import Awaitable, Callable
from typing import Any, Generic, ParamSpec, TypeVar

_P = ParamSpec("_P")
_T = TypeVar("_T")

_P2 = ParamSpec("_P2")
_T2 = TypeVar("_T2")

class Cache(Generic[_P, _T]):
    def __init__(self, fn: Callable[_P, Awaitable[_T]]) -> None:
        self.fn = fn
        
    @classmethod
    def decorate(cls, **params: Any) -> Callable[
        [Callable[_P2, Awaitable[_T2]]], Cache[_P2, _T2]
    ]:
        def decorator(f: Callable[_P2, Awaitable[_T2]]) -> Cache[_P2, _T2]:
            return Cache(f)
        return decorator
        
    def __call__(self, *args: _P.args, **kwargs: _P.kwargs) -> Awaitable[_T]:
        return self.fn(*args, **kwargs)

@Cache.decorate()
async def some_function(i: int) -> int:
    return i + 1
    
reveal_type(some_function)  # Type of "some_function" is "Cache[(i: int), int]"
reveal_type(some_function(1))  # Type of "some_function(1)" is "Awaitable[int]"
some_function()  # Argument missing for parameter "i"  (reportCallIssue)
some_function('foo')  # Argument of type "Literal['foo']" cannot be assigned to parameter "i" of type "int" in function "__call__" \
                      # "Literal['foo']" is not assignable to "int"  (reportArgumentType)

This passes mypy --strict and pyright.
